# Word Mail merge: master template?

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word, mailmerge, aspose

Currently we are using xslt to produce letters etc. The data is in xml. We have 80+ letters. The same letters are used for 2 clients/customers (businesses). The header/footer and some other pieces are included from some common base and are different for the two clients. So if I want to change the header/footer e.g. in all letters, I just have to change it in one place, and all templates for letters are updated instantly.
Its like having digital branded paper, the actual paper upon which the letter is printed is blanc, so I can send the letter by email with ease.

There are also 'blocks' like the address of the recipient, 'our reference' etc which are the same upon 90% of all the letters, the same signature (picture + name, conditionally over multiple persons).

Now (for commercial reasons) we want to use mail merge (Aspose) and I'm investigating whether some of the possibilities of xslt have some equivalent in mail merge.

We still use XSLT in a previous step, so the whole line is like:
'complex data xml'->XSLT->'mergable xml'->'mailmerge with some template'->docx/pdf

So my questions are:

- Can I define some parent template for 'digital branded paper'?
- Is there a possibility to include whole blocks?
- is it possible to include a background picture (conditionally)?

Other suggestions? Best practices? I don't seem to find the right keywords to search for.

I don't want to change all mail merge templates when e.g. a new signature must be included or they want to move it 2 cm to the left...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do mail merge, even if the mergefields are in header/footer and comments.

**Update:**

> Can I define some parent template for 'digital branded paper'?

Yes, the template needs to have MergeFields for all the blocks which needs to be separate in output letters.

> Is there a possibility to include whole blocks?

Yes, see the sample code, LetterContent1 and LetterContent2 fields, whole paragraph is replaced with a single merge field.

> is it possible to include a background picture (conditionally)?

Yes, see the sample code, I have added background watermark in this example. You can also add an image (jpg, png etc).

Below is sample code to get you started. You may give it a try to experiment and modify to suite your needs.

Word Template: [Download from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6S7uu28AdY0WkhweGVTd0E3UEk&authuser=0)

```
private void GenerateLetterFromTemplate(String template, String letter, String[] keys, String[] values, String watermarkText)
{
    // Load the template in Aspose.Words
    Aspose.Words.Document document = new Aspose.Words.Document(template);

    // Perform Mail Merge using key/value arrays. Keys should exist as MergeField in the template document
    document.MailMerge.Execute(keys, values);

    // See if watermark needs to be added
    if (watermarkText.Trim().Length > 0)
        InsertWatermarkText(document, watermarkText);

    // Save the document
    document.Save(letter);
}

private static void InsertWatermarkText(Aspose.Words.Document doc, string watermarkText)
{
    // Create a watermark shape. This will be a WordArt shape. 
    // You are free to try other shape types as watermarks.
    Aspose.Words.Drawing.Shape watermark = new Aspose.Words.Drawing.Shape(doc, Aspose.Words.Drawing.ShapeType.TextPlainText);

    // Set up the text of the watermark.
    watermark.TextPath.Text = watermarkText;
    watermark.TextPath.FontFamily = "Arial";
    watermark.Width = 500;
    watermark.Height = 100;
    // Text will be directed from the bottom-left to the top-right corner.
    watermark.Rotation = -40;
    // Remove the following two lines if you need a solid black text.
    watermark.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gray; // Try LightGray to get more Word-style watermark
    watermark.StrokeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray; // Try LightGray to get more Word-style watermark

    // Place the watermark in the page center.
    watermark.RelativeHorizontalPosition = RelativeHorizontalPosition.Page;
    watermark.RelativeVerticalPosition = RelativeVerticalPosition.Page;
    watermark.WrapType = WrapType.None;
    watermark.VerticalAlignment = Aspose.Words.Drawing.VerticalAlignment.Center;
    watermark.HorizontalAlignment = Aspose.Words.Drawing.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

    // Create a new paragraph and append the watermark to this paragraph.
    Aspose.Words.Paragraph watermarkPara = new Aspose.Words.Paragraph(doc);
    watermarkPara.AppendChild(watermark);

    // Insert the watermark into all headers of each document section.
    foreach (Section sect in doc.Sections)
    {
        // There could be up to three different headers in each section, since we want
        // the watermark to appear on all pages, insert into all headers.
        InsertWatermarkIntoHeader(watermarkPara, sect, HeaderFooterType.HeaderPrimary);
        InsertWatermarkIntoHeader(watermarkPara, sect, HeaderFooterType.HeaderFirst);
        InsertWatermarkIntoHeader(watermarkPara, sect, HeaderFooterType.HeaderEven);
    }
}

private static void InsertWatermarkIntoHeader(Aspose.Words.Paragraph watermarkPara, Section sect, HeaderFooterType headerType)
{
    Aspose.Words.HeaderFooter header = sect.HeadersFooters[headerType];

    if (header == null)
    {
        // There is no header of the specified type in the current section, create it.
        header = new Aspose.Words.HeaderFooter(sect.Document, headerType);
        sect.HeadersFooters.Add(header);
    }

    // Insert a clone of the watermark into the header.
    header.AppendChild(watermarkPara.Clone(true));
}
```

Call the method from your program, change the values as required.

```
String template = dataDir + "Letter Template.docx"; // Template
String letter = dataDir + "Dwayne M. Lajoie.docx"; // Letter

String[] keys = new string[] { "SenderCompanyName", "SenderCompanyAddress", "RecipientName", "RecipientAddress",
        "Salutation",
        "LetterContent1",
        "LetterContent2",
        "Closing",
        "SenderName"
    };
String[] values = new String[] { "Sender Corp.", "1138 Post Farm Road, Atlanta, GA 30305", "Dwayne M. Lajoie", "602 Whaley Lane, Milwaukee, WI 53212", 
        "Mr.",
        @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean porta quam ac tellus mattis, id rutrum nibh tempus. Pellentesque pretium vel erat nec sollicitudin. Vivamus consequat scelerisque fermentum. Ut ullamcorper auctor massa. Fusce sed bibendum sapien. Aenean in placerat metus. In felis velit, hendrerit eget pulvinar auctor, egestas a nisl. Aliquam in urna non nisi placerat ullamcorper ut eu turpis. Phasellus lacus nunc, tincidunt eget consequat at, aliquet quis felis. Quisque tempus ac nisl id tristique. Pellentesque nec tincidunt nulla. Integer congue dui eu tellus varius, at tincidunt magna feugiat. Quisque et arcu elit. Integer tincidunt ipsum urna, a dictum odio vulputate eget. Mauris sagittis risus felis, non dignissim magna facilisis vel.",
        @"Nam egestas dignissim mi id dapibus. Morbi volutpat augue et diam bibendum viverra. Nullam feugiat blandit libero, vitae ultrices risus. Praesent dignissim cursus metus, eget viverra eros scelerisque sit amet. Duis id porttitor nisi, vitae scelerisque sem. Sed vehicula turpis tellus, in pretium dui gravida quis. Ut vel enim ligula. Nulla facilisi.",
        "Have a nice day",
        "David C. Donohue"
    };

String watermarkText = "";

GenerateLetterFromTemplate(template, letter, keys, values, watermarkText);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read through the documentation, but couldn't find an answer to all my underlying questions. I edited my post, and would like to know your opinion/reaction.

Comment: I have updated the answer with sample code and template document. You can experiment to see if it works in your scenario. Let me know if you come across any issue.